# I had five div's if i call one div other div want to be hide?

Tags: html-lists

Herer I used hoever menu pop-up window.while hoever it will display default window . When I hoever Sub menu1 The window changes . It will happen frequently . I researched upto my extent . I can't get the soloution . PLease Suggest me a better soloution. My coding is Follows

```
<div class="csn-navigation" style="background-color:Fuchsia;">
<div class="wrapper">
    <ul class="navigation">
        <li id="cars-for-sale" >
            <a href="submenu1.aspx">Main Menu
                <i class="icon-caret">&nbsp;</i>
            </a>
                <div id="dd" class="menu-panel">
                    <span class="arrow">&nbsp;</span>
                        <div class="menu-links">
                            <ul class="menu-links" ">
                                <li id="" class="vip first" onmouseover='fnSubhover("er");'>
                                    <a href="submenu1.aspx">Sub Menu1</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="" class="vip">
                                    <a href="submenu1.aspx">Sub Menu2</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="" class="vip">
                                    <a href="submenu1.aspx">Sub Menu3</a>
                                </li>
                                <li id="" class="vip">
                                    <a href="submenu1.aspx">Sub Menu4</a>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div id="" class="menu-content" > <%-- Content of Default Menu --%>
                            <div class="category browse-body-types">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="submenu1.aspx">
                                            <img src="forward.png"/>
                                        </a>Window1
                                     </li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>


                    </div>
                    <div id="Div1" class="menu-content" > <%-- Content of Sub Menu1 --%>
                            <div class="category browse-body-types">
                                <ul>
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="submenu1.aspx">
                                            <img src="forward.png"/>
                                        </a>Window1
                                     </li>
                                 </ul>
                              </div>


                    </div>
                 </div>


          </li>
     </ul>
 </div>
```

```
            function fnSubhover(id) {
                document.getElementById("d1").style.display = "block";
                document.getElementById("dd").style.display = "none";

            }

        </script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood you correctly, you want to have all the divs hide except that one? You can do that with simple query:

```
function fnSubhover(id) {
    $('div').css('display','none');
    $('#d1').css('display','block');
}
```

Comment: u suggested the answere it's correct. and the script i used is also correct . Thank's thomas lai..I got the answer finally

Comment: <div class="menu-content">
                        <div id="subma" class="category browse-body-types">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="submenu1.aspx">
<img src="forward.png" />
</a>Product1</li></ul></div>
 <div id="submb" class="category browse-body-types">
<ul>
<li>
<a href="submenu1.aspx">
<img src="6256290-arrow-icon-blue-isolated-on-white-background.jpg" />
</a>Product1</li></ul></div>